Second order derivative is not done in pytorch
def dv():
            for k in range(n):
                z10=make_prediction(x2,t)[0]
                z1=torch.tensor(z10,requires_grad=True)
                z1[k].backward(create_graph=True)
                u_x00=x2.grad[k]
                u_t0=t2.grad[k]
                u_x0=torch.tensor(u_x00,requires_grad=True)
                u_x0.backward()
                u_xx0=x2.grad[k]

The derivative of the network with respect to x in the first order and the second order are equal, as if the second order does not work at all.
makeprediction is the model, u_x is dx/dx, def dv is the function of derivation

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
